# Laravel Call to a member function isActivated() on null

Tags: php, laravel, null

First thanks for reading this post!

I'm pretty new to Laravel, I'm overriding the `validateLogin` method in the `LoginController`. I'm calling the `isActivated` method which is in the User model under `app\User` but I get the below error, I've even hardcoded it to return true for testing. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, any advice?

```
Call to a member function isActivated() on null
```

**app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php**

```
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
  //if(User::isActivated()->isActivated() == false)
  if (Auth::user()->isActivated())
  {
      return redirect('/contact');
  }
```

**app\User.php**

```
public function isActivated()
{
    //return $this->confirmed ;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you connected? Because Auth::user() is create after the login.

Comment: @N.Lamblin - Ah I see. So how would I check the users account is activated prior to logging them in then? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Laravel has a method to do this. Look https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users

Comment: sounds like you want to check this after they are logged in `authenticated` method or as conditions on the login itself

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `isActivated()` on `null` in that context because there is no authenticated user. For the code to work you will want to first check that a user is authenticated, then whether they are activated.

```
if (Auth::user() && Auth::user()->isActivated()) {
    // Safely check that a user is authenticated and activated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're following this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authenticating-users

Your can use `Auth::attempt` method.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'active' => 1])) {
    // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
}
```